# best way to do list of tasks with multiprocessing using N workers?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

for example, it starts 5 separate workers, each is doing chunk of args for it

and this all using multiprocessing

right now im stuck with this code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def multiprocessing(func, args, workers):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(workers) as ex:
        res = ex.map(func, args)
    return list(res)


def do_stuff(arg1, arg2):
    '''it has to be executed once and do some tasks'''
    pass


def main():
    data = ...
    args = []
    for i in data:
        args.append((i, 123))
    multiprocessing(do_stuff, args, 5)

main()
```

is it right or should be changed?
the hard thing is do_stuff has to be executed only 5 times, not more and it has to get new and new args

Comment: If that code works for you, it's fine?

Comment: @AKX, im not sure that's the best way and it's working well

Comment: If it's working and you're looking to improve it, you may want to try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Your code is *not* correct. `do_stuff` takes two arguments but `ex,map(func, args)` will be passing only one argument. Also, `map` already returns a list, so your statement `return list(res)` is redundant. This will be a list of `None` values since that is what `do_stuff` is implicitly returning currently.

Comment: @Booboo thanks, but that code was just as example and i want to understand how it will exactly work
what i want: 5 workers work in queue and get new and new args
this one runs 5 workers and passes list of 5 args to each, then killing all of them and doing all again

Comment: Frankly, you're not being clear. In your original question you state, "do_stuff has to be executed only 5 times, not more and it has to get new and new args." I have no idea what that means. Your last comment doesn't make it any clearer what you are trying to do. And nothing in the code you posted makes this any clearer because it is not a complete, [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), especially since variable `data` is not specified. And `do_stuff` will be executed a precise number of times equal to `len(args)`.